# How to multiply Vectors with Double?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a sprite move back and forth with this equation here:

```
SpriteTexture sprite;
Vector2 position;
Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(0, 100), 
        p2 = new Vector2(0, 0);
double currentTime = 0, timestep = 0.01;
...    
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
 position = currentTime * p1 + (1 - currentTime) * p2;
 currentTime += timestep;
 if (currentTime >= 1 || currentTime <= 0)
 {
   timestep *= -1;
 }
}
```

I keep getting the error: "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2"

Comment: Have you considered using floats for currentTime and timestep isntead of doubles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Vector2.Multiply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198129.aspx) or converting your double to a float, and multiplying the `Vector2` by the `currentTime`

**1.**

```
position = Vector2.Multiply(p1, (float)currentTime) +
    Vector2.Multiply(p2, (float)(1 - currentTime));
```

**2.**

```
position = (p1 * (float)currentTime) + (p2 * (float)(1 - currentTime));
```

Comment: Can you verify that it is increasing the value?

Comment: How are you drawing your sprite?

Comment: Figured it was going to be that, glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Vector2.Multiply Method (Vector2, Single)
```

API as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198129.aspx

You cannot multiply a vector with a double using * operator and this is what the error is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Vector2 supports multiplication by floats, or you can manually multiply the individual components of a vector by the double (which you'd cast to a float).

For example:

```
 position = currentTime * (float)p1 + ((float)(1 - currentTime)) * p2;
```

Or if you wanted to do individual multiplication of a vector

```
 // Assuming myVector is a Vector3:
 myVector.X *= (float)someDoubleValue;
 myVector.Y *= (float)someDoubleValue;
 myVector.Z *= (float)someDoubleValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing problem

```
position = currentTime * p1 + (1 - currentTime) * p2
```

Here you are trying to multiply `currentTime` a `double` with `p1` a `Vector` Instance.

To multiply a Vector instance you need  to use [Vector.Multiply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.multiply.aspx)